# Advantages of update "targetSdkVersion" in android project

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand the reason of update **targetSdkVersion** in my project.

Let's me explain,

When I first created my project I set targetSdkVersion to **22**.

Now I can update it to 26 if I want, but... **why?**

**If i do it, it is necessary to explicitly request for permissions in code** (targetSdkVersion 23)

I couldn't find any documentation related with the Advantages of update targetSdkVersion.

I test my app everyday with mobile phone with Android Oreo, Nougat, etc. I know my app works great with targetSdkVersion 22.

But, again, I have to destinate time to fix lots of issues that I will get when I update it (request for permission, may be some UI issues, etc). I need technical reasons to warrant the time I will destinate

Of course one of the reason is maintenance, because you are out of date, etc. Great. **But I'm looking for technical reasons to answer the question**

E.g: "If you update your targetSdk from 22 to 23, you will have an improvement 
in how your app uses the battery of your mobile phone".

It will be great if someone can attach official documentation related with the improvement for each targetSdkVersion.

**My compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion are 26.**

Thanks and good coding!

**EDIT:** I know the definition of targetSdkVersion, but what I mean: If my app works great, why I need to update it? I don't have to implements new features.

Comment: you update the target sdk to gain access to the new APIs. thats it. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html ---- "Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces behavior changes as well as new features and APIs that you can take advantage of in your apps."

Comment: please checkout the docs for `targetSdkVersion` here, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

Comment: Access to new APIs. and most importantly the User experience . See after Lollipop Runtime permission introduces for security reasons, A end user should know that the app he/she is using do not using her/his data in background without permission . And now M,N, O are launched so users are pretty much used to runtime permission architecture . So i guess if your app does not have it it will make a bad impression to end users . This is just my opinion .[Here](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) is blog discussing the same.

Comment: Using a recent targetSDK [will soon be mandatory if you want to distribute your app via the PlayStore](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html).

Comment: I've just edit my question. @DroiDev: I don't have to add new features.

Comment: @petey: these documentation doesn' t explain the improvement for each targetSdkVersion.

Comment: @ADM: Instead of bad impression to the user, what I see is: users that don't understand what to do when those security popup means (The result of that is: ok I won't uses this app, or a email to the support team)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need technical reasons to warrant the time I will destinate

First, [you will no longer be able to ship updated versions of your app on the Play Store, if you fail to upgrade your `targetSdkVersion`](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html). It is possible that other app distribution channels will follow suit.

Second, if you want to use the latest Android Support Library versions — perhaps for bug fixes — you will want to upgrade your `targetSdkVersion` to match them.

Third, you enable features that benefit the user, such as runtime permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "enable features that benefit the user", such as runtime permissions, is one of the benefit. I heard benefit related with the battery and users experience. Is any documentation when I can read the every single benefit? is it exist?

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten: "Is any documentation when I can read the every single benefit?" -- in general, that sort of information is covered in the release notes for the OS version. For example, [this section](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#o-apps) lists what will change on Android 8.0+ devices once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to 26 or higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the information that I was looking for.

Comment: hi, do I need to update gradle and gradle plugin version if I'm updatin min target sdk?

Comment: @blackHawk: Generally, no, but some features might require upgrading the tools. Ideally, you keep your Gradle, Android Gradle Plugin, and `targetSdkVersion` values up to date.

Comment: But after I upgrade targetSdkVersion to 31 my app stopped working on android 12 here is my Q., please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502338/parsing-the-package-issue-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

As others already said in comments, you get access to new api's and forward compatibility is disabled ([check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) for a more detailed description).

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) you can see the difference between all the versions.